# show underlined menu items by default

Tags: 10.10, gnome, menu

in the previous releases of ubuntu menu items were *underlined* by default so i didnt have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show them. however in maverick one has to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to view them. how can i set ubuntu to show underlined menu items by default?
is there a setting in *gconf-editor*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Ubuntu bug 403691](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtk/+bug/403691), try editing your `.gtkrc` and adding:

```
gtk-auto-mnemonics = 0
```

The `.gtkrc` file to edit will either be in `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` or your current theme's `gtkrc`, e.g. `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`.

I'm guessing you need to log out and back in for it to take effect.

Comment: thanks a lot. but i think it was rather an annoying feature than a bug :)

Comment: This does not only underlines *menu items* but also keyboard shortcuts in the dialog boxes.