# Always show keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I can't get the keyboard shortcuts (or "mnemonics") to be permanently underlined in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine.

- I've tried [modifying the theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23110/show-underlined-menu-items-by-default) (even checking that yes, it was Ambiance), didn't work.
- Without undoing the previous change, I tried [dconf-editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447609/keep-menu-and-dialog-mnemonic-underlining-always-on-whether-by-default-or-pe) as well, which didn't work either.
  Even after a full reboot of the machine, the UI still waits for me to press Alt for *one full second* before showing the shortcuts.

Not only did they copy this **misfeature** from Windows, *they actually made it worse!* At least in Windows even when it's not disabled, it's instant.

How do I fix this?